# How to modify sample Windows Store App built using Windows Azure Mobile Service

Tags: windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services

I have created a Windows Store App using Windows Azure Mobile Service, as explained by Scott Gu in channel 9 video - http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services/Introduction-to-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services

As explained in video and quick start tutorial, I have created a 'ToDoItem' table and I am able to run the app as expected. I wanted to know, if there is anyway to modify 'TodoItem' table structure and add few more columns to it and enhance Windows Store App to map those columns.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes why not. You have to just create new columns in database dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add more columns to the table you created, all you need to do is to add a new property to the class and insert a new item in the service - by default tables in Azure Mobile Services have a dynamic schema feature, in that they'll add new columns if a request arrives with additional members.

This is shown in the [Get Started With Data tutorial in MSDN](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-dotnet/) (see section "Add a new table to the mobile service", note under step 5).